# cannot match any routes after login with return url Angular 9

Tags: angular, authentication, redirect, logging

I'm using Angular current version and I'm building this app for testing (fakebackend and so on). Everything seems in proper place, i get signed in, credentials are stored in an array but when I try to login, I run into some issues. Here's the revelant code:

Routes ts

```
 {path:'home', component: HomeComponent}, 
  {path:'login', component:LoginComponent},
  {path:'signup', component: SignupComponent},
  {path:'detail/:id', component: UserDetailComponent},
  {path:'', redirectTo:'/login', pathMatch:'full'},
```

The Login TS file

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      userName: ['', Validators.required],
      password: [null, Validators.required]
    })
  }

  get userName(){return this.form.get('userName')}
  get password(){return this.form.get('password')}

  onSubmit() {
    if (this.form.invalid)
      return
    let credentials = {
      userName: this.userName.value,
      password: this.password.value
    }
    this.authService.login(credentials)
      .pipe(first())
      .subscribe(data => {

        let returnUrl = this.route.snapshot.queryParamMap.get('returnUrl');
        this.router.navigate([ returnUrl ||'/home '])
      })
  }
```

When I try to login with valid credentials (stored in localStorage) I get this error:

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'home%20'
Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'home%20'
    at ApplyRedirects.noMatchError (router.js:4396)
```

So, I guess I must be doing something wrong but I cant figure what it is. Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove the space in route link

```
this.router.navigate([ returnUrl ||'/home ']) //remove the space
```

change to:

```
this.router.navigate([ returnUrl ||'/home'])
```

Comment: that was it, with strings every carefull is never too much ;) thank you